# ImportError: cannot import name "twiml" from partially initialized module

Tags: python

I keep getting an error when I run this, and I copied and pasted the code exactly as Twilio said to do. I followed their steps to run Homebrew, tried uninstalling and then reinstalling Twilio, but I am stuck. Anyone have any ideas?

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client


# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from             twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See    http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['account sid']
auth_token = os.environ['auth token']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages \
            .create(
                 body="Join Earth's mightiest     heroes. Like Kevin Bacon.",
                 from_='+1twilio number',
                 to='+1my number'
             )

print(message.sid)
```

Comment: Are you running a supported Python version for all modules you're using?

Comment: Please post the entire traceback message so we can see the call stack and failing line.